# Как восстановить бекап на определенную дату?

Tags: sql-server

Есть такие файлы бекапов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу восстановить бекап на 10 часов 6 числа.

Пробовал выбирать бекап за 11:44, но выбрать желаемую дату не дает.

Подскажите, как правильно достичь желаемого?

Comment: Вам нужно выбрать последний full backup до нужного времени + все transaction backup-ы, заканчивая тем, что сделан после нужного времени

Comment: Ну или выбрать вообще все файлы и тыкнуть в таймлайн

Comment: Вот такую ошибку выдает при попытке несколько файлов добавить http://prntscr.com/p2slys

Comment: по ошибке - при бэкапе (не при ресторе) было указано сразу несколько файлов.Поищите вторую половину бэкапа - https://serverfault.com/a/460487/221154

Comment: ну или вы не угадали с комбинацией. попробуйте выбрать все файлы